# Как перебором элементов в списке перейти к первому элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо это сделать с помощью чистого JS или jQuery

Есть список элементов:

```
<ul>
    <li>Первый</li>
    <li class="active">Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо с интервалом в 1,5 секунды:

1. Находить элемент списка с классом .active ("Два") и убирать у
   него данный класс
2. Находить следующий элемент в списке ("Три") и добавлять ему класс .active

Проблема в том, когда скрипт доходит до последнего элемента списка ("Четыре"). Как сделать так, чтобы доходя до последнего элемента списка - скрип следующим элементом выбирал первый в списке ("Один")?

Comment: Покажи, как пытался реализовать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реализация на jQuery

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
 interval = 1500; //Полторы секунды
 setInterval(function(){
  count = $("ul li").length; //Получаем общее кол.во элементов
  index = $("ul li.active").index() + 1; //Ищем порядковый номер элемента и добавляем +1 что бы получить индекс следующего
  $("ul li.active").removeClass("active"); //Убираем у текущего элемента класс active
  if(index== count) index = 0; //Если индекс выходит за рамки, ставим 0, что бы начать с 1 элемента
  $("ul li").eq(index).addClass("active"); //Добавляем класс .active нужному элементу
 }, interval);
});
```

```css
li{
   color: blue;
 }
 li.active{
   color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>Первый</li>
    <li class="active">Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень схоже с предыдущим автором, но коль уж начал делать - решил и показать.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  const interval = 1500;
  const elements = $("ul li");
  const count = elements.length;
  
  setInterval(function(){
   let curElement = $("ul li.active");
   let index = elements.index(curElement);
      curElement.removeClass("active");
   elements.eq(++index%count).addClass("active");
  }, interval);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Первый</li>
    <li class="active">Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
</ul>
```